# Вывод счетчика обработки данных

Tags: javascript, ajax, циклы

Через `for` запускаю функцию с ajax запросом через post. Функция посылает данные на сервер и после их обработки должна вывести в счетчике значение "*обработано n из m*".

Данные выводятся только после завершения цикла и мне показывает только последний результат. Если смотреть в консоле, то там все идет по циклу.

Каким образом обновлять счетчик после каждого ajax запроса?

```
    function createObject() {
        var request_type;
        var browser = navigator.appName;
        if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
            request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        return request_type;
    }

    var http = createObject();

    for(var i=0; i < countEl; i++) {
        run(data[i], i, countEl);
    }

    function run(data, i, countEl) {
        http.open('post', '/modules/index.php?load', false);
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        http.send("data="+data+"&counter="+i);

        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            counter(i, countEl);
        }
   }

        function counter(i, m) {
            var n = i + 1;
            console.log('Загружено '+n+' из '+m);
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = 'Загружено '+n+' из '+m;
        }
```

Comment: что за объект http?

Comment: function createObject() {
 var request_type;
 var browser = navigator.appName;
 if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
 request_type = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }else{
 request_type = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 return request_type;
 }
 var http = createObject();

Comment: добавь это в вопрос

Comment: Так тут аджаксом и не пахнет

Comment: подскажите тогда пожалуйста чем тут пахнет и в какую сторону копать

Comment: @ANTiK, тут xhr, ajax это метод jquery. Grundy меня поправит, если не прав

Comment: @Doofy, нет, ajax, это как раз технология, метод jQuery это просто обертка над XmlHttpRequest, но да, тут не ajax, потому что первая `A` в аббревиатуре ajax - Асинхронный - а тут происходит синхронный запрос

Comment: @Grundy, ну вот. Можно создать переменную и приравнять её к нулю. Когда приходит ответ, плюсуем к переменной 1

Comment: К сожалению асинхронный запрос не проходит, сервер, который получает данные - почему-то отказывается обрабатывать данные переданные таким образом

Comment: А, там не так. Приходит один ответ на один запрос. Через цикл отправляются запросы, а приходит всегда только последний, правильно?

Comment: да, но в консоле все идет нормально.. если допустим прерывать цикл alertom то в счетчик изменяется после каждого алерта

Comment: Я могу дать ответ, если вопрос будет поставлен в лоб. Отправляются сразу куча запросов через цикл. Нужно выводить на страничке сколько пришло ответов?

Comment: можно ли вывести номер каждой итерации цикла при получении положительного ответа от ajax запроса подобным образом. Если нет, то подскажите в какую сторону стоит обратить взгляд

Comment: Ну а чёж нельзя? Мжно же не посылать итерацию, а просто приплюсовывать переменную при каждом ответе

Comment: так цикл отправляет данные из массива в запрос, как тут без него-то обойтись, наверно я забыл указать это в коде :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<span id='download'>Загружено 0 из 10</span>
```

```js
count = 0;

for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
    send('do=');
}

function send(s) {
    request(new XMLHttpRequest());

    function request(xhr) {
        xhr.open('POST', 'a.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send(s);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if(xhr.status == 200) {
                    count++;
        document.querySelector('#download').innerHTML = 'Загружено ' + count + ' из 10';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['do'])) {
    sleep(rand(1, 5));
    echo 'ok';
}
```

---

При синхронном запросе inner не успевает сработать, на помощь приходит `setTimeout`

```
max = 10;
send('do=', 0);

function send(s, i) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'a.php', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(s);
    if(xhr.status == 200) {
        document.querySelector('#download').innerHTML = 'Загружено ' + i + ' из ' + max;

        if(i < max) {
            i++;
            setTimeout(function() { send('do=', i); }, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Запросы асинхронные. Код работает даже на IE8, я проверил :) Останется только менять запросы в for

Comment: gif! почему не snippet? :-D

Comment: @Grundy, но там маханькая гифуля)

Comment: дело в том: xhr.open('POST', 'a.php', true); - когда выставляю true сервер на который отправляются данные обрабатывает только первый запрос и все

Comment: @ANTiK, там запуск питона чтоли или какая-то штукенция типа arduino?

Comment: нет там API vk :(

Comment: @ANTiK, запилил синхронный запрос